# Insert into select from multiple tables(join? ) and constants

Tags: sql-server, select, join, insert

I am trying to do an insert using values from other tables AND constants. I have found partial  answer on SO but i can't manage to finish the stored procedure. I should be doing something like

```
INSERT INTO table1(value1, value2, value3, value4)
SELECT 
    @value1,
    value2,
    value3,
    @value4 
FROM table2 WHERE table2.id = @value2; -- not sure
```

But i must use some kind of join to get data from the 3rd table as well and i don't know how.

I have 3 tables.
i want to insert like this

```
INSERT INTO table1(field1, field2, field3, field4)
```

As for values

```
field1 = @field1
SELECT field2_type FROM table2 WHERE field2ID = @field2 -- field2
SELECT field3_type FROM table3 WHERE field3ID = @field3 -- field3
field4 = @field4
```

I am using SQL Server 2012

table1 looks like:

```
ID       int, PK
Name     varchar
Function int
Type     int
Age      int
```

table2 looks like:

```
FunctionID           int
FunctionDescription  varchar
```

table3 looks like:

```
TypeID               int
TypeDescription      varchar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answer. In case someone else is looking for it:

```
INSERT INTO table1(field1, field2, field3, field4)
select
field1 = @field1,
field2=  (SELECT TOP 1 field2_type FROM table2 WHERE field2ID = @field2 order by (select NULL)),
field3 = (SELECT TOP 1 field3_type FROM table3 WHERE field3ID = @field3 order by (select NULL)),
field4 = @field4
```

Answer (score 0):

very unclear what you said but use UNION if you want get all or use JOIN

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT *
FROM table2 
UNION
SELECT * FROM table3
```